# How many users are connecting from North Korea?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_in_North_Korea) in Wikipedia:

> North Korea is almost completely isolated from the rest of the world
> and, while there is a public telephone network, there is no broadband
> data network. According to one report released in 2009, many North
> Koreans had never heard of the Internet.

Is there any data available indicating whether anyone is connecting to one of the Stack Exchange sites with an IP address from North Korea?

(Using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64094/get-top-users-by-country) I could find two users who claim that they are from North Korea, but that's not very conclusive.)

Comment: Nice try, North Korean Government.

Comment: I certainly hope no mod/dev will make public that info for specific users.

Comment: What @Mat said, but I *would* be interested in the raw numbers

Comment: The interwebs in North Korea are weird - you can only connect when there is a double rainbow in the sky. I don't understand why, that's just the way it is.

Comment: [This guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164015/kim-jong-woo) looks pretty North Korean to me.

Comment: Who whoa WHOA!!! **This is Wikipedia.** Did you read the citation for that line? Apparently "`Song-hee had only practiced moving her fingers on the keyboard. She had never heard of the Internet.`" somehow becomes equivalent to "`According to one report released in 2009, many North Koreans had never heard of the Internet`"...

Comment: It's pretty easy to answer it: It is one more than you would think, and a thousand less than they should be. `:)`

Comment: ...and furthermore, what are their questions, compared to others? Any anomalous questions?

Comment: I thought North Korean Government prefer to make connections...with nukes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to Google Analytics we had a couple dozen daily visits between July and October 2011, but then the number dropped to zero and we haven't had a visit from that country since October 25th.

[image: chart]

Comment: I almost feel like they're reaching out with SOS messages with that tongue-in-cheek [pigeon IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers).  Man I hope one day everyone has Internet....

Comment: did some poor guy get executed for transgressions?

Comment: Isn't it odd that Quantcast feels different? (And in general, Google [tends to show larger figures](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-traffic-still-growing/) than Quantcast does?)

Comment: It's possible that those numbers are just a measurement error. The IP->Country lookup tables aren't perfect. I had a website where most of my "Australian" users were actually (South) Koreans.

Comment: Or, any chance Google is being blocked in North Korea? (@CodeInChaos)

Comment: The way the graph zeroes out abruptly has such a dramatic feeling to it.

Comment: @Camilo, then let's hope it's indeed about blocking Google Analytics instead. I'd even block Analytics if I were a big company with trade secrets. Imagine how a country that thinks the US is an enemy in every possible respect, feels about a US company tracking web visits on many websites?

Comment: @Arjan Yes, indeed blocking Google Analytics seems likely. Maybe the guy who blocked Google Analytics had to look up how to do it in Stack Overflow? (I really feel sad for smart people on such a country).

Answer (score 9):

Quantcast says, for Stack Overflow: about [432](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com/geo/countries?contains=korea&sortby=name&sortorder=asc) per month (out of 14.9 million in total).

For [SE wide details](http://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc?country=KP), you'll need to add the country code `KP` to the URL manually, as it's not listed otherwise.

Comment: Those will be the scientists and engineers working on the country's nuclear program googling for results and ending up at SO. I hope they're up voting the good answers.

Comment: That may very well be true, but somehow Quantcast thinks a few of them [are less than 18 years old](http://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc?country=KP).

Comment: @Arjan - What's hard to believe there? Kids program at 12, 13 , etc

Comment: Sure, @Adel, but even in North Korea, I'd somehow doubt those would be working in a nuclear plant, like slugster suggested?

Comment: I started programming at 11 :P

Comment: And at what age did you start working in a nuclear plant, @Benny? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Ever since I spent all of my pocket money on one